# Athena (Presto) SQL window functions

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, window-functions, amazon-athena, presto

say I have the following data in Athena:

```
id      ts
uid1    1499672134268
uid1    1499672134292
uid1    1499672136189
uid1    1499672136212
uid1    1499719927907
uid1    1499719927940
uid1    1499719927975
uid1    1499719927999
uid2    1499670000000
uid2    1499670000010
uid2    1499688880010
```

I want to rank it so:

```
rank    id      ts
1       uid1    1499672134268
1       uid1    1499672134292
1       uid1    1499672136189
1       uid1    1499672136212
2       uid1    1499719927907
2       uid1    1499719927940
2       uid1    1499719927975
2       uid1    1499719927999
1       uid2    1499670000000
1       uid2    1499670000010
2       uid2    1499688880010
```

the logic is:
the difference between the min value in the second group and the max value in the first group is larger than `x`

I am thinking some combination of `dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY id ... )` could resolve it, but I am a total newbie to window functions in SQL.

Thanks

Comment: what is `x` in this example? do you mean resetting the group if the difference from previous ts > x?

Comment: exactly, x is just a certain threshold

Comment: Clarify the logic using the data sample. Your post definition does not match your reply to @vkp

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lag` and get the difference from the previous row's `ts` and reset it using a running sum, when it goes > x.

```
select id,ts,1+sum(col) over(partition by id order by ts) as rnk
from (select id,ts
      ,case when ts-lag(ts,1,ts) over(partition by id order by ts) > 3000 then 1 else 0 end as col
      from tbl
     ) t
```

Replace `3000` (x) in the `case` expression with the desired value.